# PJSIP (PJSUA2) - OPUS codec

Tags: audio, sip, pjsip, flac

Is it possible to configure [PJSIP (PJSUA2)](http://www.pjsip.org/) to use [OPUS](https://www.opus-codec.org) codec?

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a way (ubuntu 14.04, require PJSIP >= 2.5):

1. Install opus@1.1.2 from source using following commands:

   ```
   $ curl -sO http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/opus/opus-1.1.2.tar.gz
   $ tar xzvf opus-1.1.2.tar.gz \
     && rm opus-1.1.2.tar.gz \
     && cd opus-1.1.2 \
     && ./configure \
     && make && make check 

   $ sudo make install \
     && sudo ldconfig 

   $ ldconfig -p | grep opus
   > libopus.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libopus.so
   ```
2. Install PJSIP@2.5 according to http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1904:

   ```
   curl -sO http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.5/pjproject-2.5.tar.bz2
   tar xjf pjproject-2.5.tar.bz2 \
    && rm pjproject-2.5.tar.bz2 \
    && cd pjproject-2.5/ \
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-opus=/usr/local/ \
    && make dep && make

   $ sudo make install && sudo ldconfig
   ```
3. Make sure OPUS is available

   ```
   std::cout << "Available codecs:\n";
   for (auto c : Endpoint::instance()->codecEnum()) {
     std::cout << " - " << c->codecId << " (priority: " << static_cast<int>(c->priority) << ")\n";
   }
   ```

> Available codecs:
>
> - speex/16000/1 (priority: 130)
> - speex/8000/1 (priority: 129)
> - speex/32000/1 (priority: 128)
> - iLBC/8000/1 (priority: 128)
> - GSM/8000/1 (priority: 128)
> - PCMU/8000/1 (priority: 128)
> - PCMA/8000/1 (priority: 128)
> - G722/16000/1 (priority: 128)
> - **opus/48000/2** (priority: 128)
> - L16/44100/1 (priority: 0)
> - L16/44100/2 (priority: 0)
> - L16/8000/1 (priority: 0)
> - L16/8000/2 (priority: 0)
> - L16/16000/1 (priority: 0)
> - L16/16000/2 (priority: 0)

4. Adjust priority using `Endpoint::instance()->codecSetPriority("opus/48000", 131);`

Comment: Hi, I got following error when - skipping incompatible /usr/local//lib/libopus.so. Any clue ? Building pjsip using --use-ndk-cflags. Does it means that I have to build opus using different compilers ?

Comment: If you're using NDK to build `pjsua2.so` then you also have to build opus with NDK.